# Html and Body set height

Tags: html, css

If I set the below CSS:

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Hello
</div>
```

the container does not fill the full height area
but if i change the min-height: 100vh with height:100vh
it works !
Why does this happen?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a very old bug in Webkit (that is, Chrome and Safari). Bug report [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26559). Ten years old now and no fix, that's wild!

> When a block's height is determined by min-height/max-height, children with percentage heights are sized incorrectly

Comment: Why do you think this is a webkit browser?

Comment: The "bug" is marked as FIXED. There is something else going on but I don't have time to go into it. This is not the answer.

Comment: It was resolved as FIXED in 2013, but started getting reports again in 2017. Might be a regression.

Comment: See [Comment 34](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26559#c34) Browser behaviour meets the CSS spec.

Comment: @ManosKanellopoulos this is not a bug, check the duplicate for more details

Answer (score 0):

If you set the container to 100%, the container will size only to fit to 100% of the height of the contents of what's in the container div.

100vh sets the container to 100 vertical height, where vertical height is the full height of the page.

Hope this helps you understand the difference

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Hello<br> How are you?
</div>
```

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Hello<br> How are you?
</div>
```

Comment: What about min-height: 100vh? Does this set the height of body?

Comment: Sorry Rachel I though that as the container is child of body and the body has height 100vh from min-height, the height of 100% of the container it will fill all body height

Comment: @ManosKanellopoulos if height was used instead of min-height, the container would be 100vh, but as you may not want this all your child classes to be 100vh (and it would override % heights of classes), you may not want  to use this. Yes, min-height sets the height for the body.

Comment: Rachel, this doesn't answer his question. He's asking why the html and body can be set to `min-height: 100vh`, but the child div with `height: 100%` doesn't fill that height.

Comment: @symlink my answer did address the question, He asked why the difference and I answered. If he wants to investigate inheritance further, well that's his own business. I specifically said that classes  would be affected (if he had experimented further he would've discovered the same is not true for ids)

Comment: My question is that @symlink mention but yes Rachel you have right for the ids!!

Comment: @RachelGallen see Benjamin's answer, the question is about a bug in Webkit.

Comment: Benjamin I did not know that is a bug!!!!

Comment: @symlink it's not a bug at all, it's a logical behavior .. height:100% will fail to auto in the case of using min-height on the parent element because height consider **height** of the parent element no it's min-height.

Comment: @ManosKanellopoulos *and the body has height 100vh from min-height, the height of 100% of the container it will fill all body height* --> no the body doesn't have a height equal to 100vh but a **min-height**. There is a huge difference. The height of the body is auto and vary between min-height value and the height of the content. If you have a content that is taking more than 100vh the body will have its *computed* height bigger than 100vh

Comment: Temani Afif I think you have right. That is the correct answer